# Вывод списка статей, что генерятся (меняются) раз в неделю

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, кто знает такую штуку.

Нужно выводить название статьи.

Выводить нужно 10 статей случайных, но только так, что бы случайность не генерировалась на ходу, а генерилась, скажем, раз в неделю. Один раз прописывался вывод 10 случайных статей, и они потом не менялись.

Comment: выбираете раз в неделю случайные статьи. Записываете нп в базу идентификатор статьи и дату генерирования. При открытии страницы проверяете - если в базе есть статьи за последнюю неделю - используем их, если нету - выбираем опять 10 случайных - в базу их.

Comment: По крону раз  в неделю создаете список из 10 статей. Сохраняете его в БД. А скрипты просто читают этот готовый список.

Comment: Пишете алгоритм, согласно которого статьи выбираются в зависимости от номера недели в году. Можете добавить влияние номера года, чтобы каждый год статьи не повторялись.

Answer (score 0):

Вычисляйте номер недели x и делайте запрос WP_Query с `'orderby' => 'RAND(x)'`. Выдает посты в случайном порядке, но этот порядок зависит от числа внутри строки. Для `'RAND(5)'` порядок всегда будет одним, а для `'RAND(7)'` - всегда другим.

И не нужны никакие ухищрения с хранением выборки в базе, php-скриптами, заданиями по cron - вообще ничего. Все решение в 1 строчке, потому что такой функционал уже реализован в mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Я этот алгоритм вижу следующим образом.

Например, у вас 10 записей и вам нужно получить 4 уникальных случайных элемента. Создаете массив из 10 элементов со значениями от 1 до 10.

1. Сортируете массив случайным образом.
2. «Вынимаете» случайным образом образом элемент из массива. Если нужного количества случайных уникальных элементов не накопилось (4 по примеру) — возвращаетесь к шагу 1.

Как игра «Русское лото». Когда из мешка достаете случайный бочонок с числом. И мешочек каждый раз перемешивается».

---

**Нюансы:**

1. Значения элементов в исходном массиве, из которого случайным образом выбираем элементы могут быть как IDшниками статей, но тогда вопрос идут ли они попорядку и ничего ли не нужно пропускать?
2. Если статьи, которые будут заменяться не должны присутствовать в новой недели — их просто можно «удалить» из массива, из которого выбираются случайные значения.

**Исходя из 1 и 2 пункта я бы делал так:**

1. С учетом того, что IDшники статей могут не идти один за другим и/или
   какие-то статьи скрываться из выдачи вообще — для начала я бы создал
   отдельное поле в БД и в каждую следующую статью увеличивал значение
   на единицу. Думаю понятно для чего. Из выборки также исключив те
   статьи, которые уже выбраны в качестве 10.
2. Зная общее количество элементов — выбирал из них нужное количество случайных уникальных элементов (значений) согласно вышеописанному алгоритму.

**Вариант решения (получения случайных уникальных записей)**

1. Пронумировываем записи статей, как описывал выше.  Не забыв во время проставления значений исключить те 10 статей, которые уже выводятся (Если они не должны участвовать в выборке). Получаем количество записей, записываем в `$count`.

```php
<?php

function getRandomUniqueElements($count, $lenght) {

    $elements = [];

    if ($count > $lenght) {
        throw new Exception('Ай-ай-ай...');
    }

    $array = range(1, $lenght);

    shuffle($array);

    while ($count) {

        $i = rand(0, count($array) - 1);

        $elements[] = $array[$i];

        unset($array[$i]);

        $array = array_values($array);

        $count--;
    }

    return $elements;
}
```

И получаем результат в виде этого. Где значения — статьи для вывода (не ID статьи, а что сами «проставляли»).

```php
<?php

print_r(getRandomUniqueElements(10, 200));

// Array
// (
//     [0] => 87
//     [1] => 198
//     [2] => 78
//     [3] => 1
//     [4] => 41
//     [5] => 11
//     [6] => 16
//     [7] => 108
//     [8] => 188
//     [9] => 39
// )
```

Не считаю алгоритм эффективным, но пока лучше не могу придумать.

Кто хорошо влаладеет MySQL — может наверно это прямо в БД процедурой сделать.

**Если будете это делать через PHP-скрипт — то лучше настроить по расписанию (cron) раз в неделю в нужное для вас время.**