# Пост дня Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нужно отображать одну запись дня из перечисленных категорий в виджете Wordpress (или в кранем случае в коде шаблона).  Как отобразить одну рендомную запись уже разобрался, а вот что бы эта запись "висела" весь день и только на следующий день заменялась - так и не расковырял.  Кто нибудь, что то подобное реализовывал? Поделитесь, плз, идеей.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701028/220220

Comment: @KAGGDesign это не совсем то, что я хотел.  Сейчас добавлю ответ с реализацией

Comment: Это ровно то, что сказано в вопросе. И не надо никаких файлов с датой. Все выполняется одним запросом в базу.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, как я реализовал задуманное:

1. с помощью стандартной функции получил случайный ID записи из необходимой категории;
2. записал простой текстовый файл следующего содержимого: id|текущая_дата_+1_день
3. при выводе поста дня открываю сохраненный файл и получаю из него ID и дату до которой действителен этот ID;
4. сверяю текущую дату с датой сохранной в файле. Если текущая дата отличается от сохраненной - просто отображаю запись с ID из файла. Если даты совпадают - генерирую новый ID и новую дату+1 день и перезаписываю файл.

На этом, собственно, вопрос можно считать закрытым.
Если подобный функционал кому то еще будет полезен - стучитесь, расскажу подробнее.